# Framework for adding users/groups/permissions functionality to an application (possibly integrating with AD)?

Tags: .net, security

I am looking to see if there is a good library or framework that I can use to simplify adding user/group/permission management to a .Net application (4.0 VS2010).  If the framework can work on it's own or integrate with Active Directory that would be a huge bonus.

So far I have found [Visual Guard](http://www.visual-guard.com/), if you have any experience using Visual Guard to provide user/group/permission functionality I definitely want to hear your feedback on how you liked working with it, pitfalls and benefits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use Declarative security... here is a link to the [MSDN Security Action Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securityaction.aspx) which I have used quite often, particularly in web apps to insure proper credentials

Comment: I didn't realize there was a built-in declarative system for security.  I am still evaluating other options but this is great, thanks!